# Hirearchial dynamic grouping by grouping sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make a hirearichial report using grouping sets in sql

The user will pass the columns to be grouped as comma seperated parameter to the stored procedure

for eg: if user needs to group by country then by region then by deptno
he will send as parameter for eg:

```
@grouplist='Country,Region,DeptNo'
```

the columns to be grouped will be dynamic.It will be send as parameter to the stored procedure.i cannot use ssrs reports.This is the query I used to generate the reports

```
    --select Country,region,Deptno , Count(EmpNo) EmpCount, 
--Sum(Sal) Total, GROUPING_ID(Country, region,Deptno) AS GrpLevel  
--from emp 
--group by GROUPING SETS(( Country,region,Deptno),(Country,Region),(Country) ,()) having country is not null

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'select '+@grouplist +' , Count(EmpNo) EmpCount, 
 Sum(Sal) Total, GROUPING_ID(' + @grouplist + ') AS GrpLevel  
 from emp 
 group by GROUPING SETS( ' +@MC +'   ,()) having country is not null 
 order by ' + @grouplist

 -- Select @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

The Output I am getting is as below

[image: Current Output]

Actual Output needed

[image: Actual Output Needed]

is there any option to show group by columns in a single column as output.here the problem is group by columns is coming as parameter to the stored procedure.
Any help appreciated.

sample data is as below

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Will you care to throw some sample data ?Dynamic sql is not needed.once you can try group by with Rollup.

Comment: @kumarHarsh column to be grouped is send by the user. ie why it is made dynamic

Comment: @user1554650, since you are already using Excel, why don't you simply return ungrouped result and use Excel pivot tables to group by?

Comment: @Alex I am not using excel. This is the data available in table. I need it to be done in sql query

Comment: @user1554650, as a suggestion you need to do this kind of output formatting in another tool (like Excel). Doing it in SQL is painful to say the least. To answer your immideate question, yes it is possible (what isn't?) but it involves some messy code, and messier still since you want it to be dynamic.

Comment: As a suggestion to get started you can use `COALESCE` to get something like: COALESCE( DeptNo, Region, Country ) AS [GroupBy] . Note: the order of columns is important.

Answer (score 0):

**Just try to write one outer query:I have consider your sql statement as inner query.**

with #temp as

(

select 'india' as country,NULL as Region,CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR) as deptno
,5 as empcount,7875 as Grptotal

UNION ALL

select 'india' as country,'Karnataka' as Region,CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR) as deptno
,3 as empcount,5475 as Grptotal

UNION ALL

select 'india' as country,'Karnataka' as Region,CAST( 20 AS VARCHAR) as deptno
,1 as empcount,2975 as Grptotal

UNION ALL

select 'india' as country,'Karnataka' as Region,CAST( 30 AS VARCHAR) as deptno
,2 as empcount,2500 as Grptotal

)

SELECT

COALESCE(X.deptno,X.Region,X.country) AS grpby,X.empcount,X.Grptotal

FROM

(

SELECT NULL AS  country,NULL AS Region, NULL AS deptno

) AS DUMMY

CROSS APPLY

(

select

country,Region,deptno,empcount,Grptotal

from #temp

)x

**Cross apply here is to dynamically select country,region,deptno**

Let me know if you have any querires